# Counterpoint to: De mortuis nil nisi bene [dicendum]

Tags: classical-latin

There's an old, and I guess relatively famous, aphorism "*[De mortuis nil nisi bene dicendum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_mortuis_nil_nisi_bonum)*" ("Of the dead speak nothing but good").

I'm wondering if there are any classical Latin counterpoints or rebuttals to this.  In particular I wonder one might something to the effect: "Criticize the departed only with love and noble intentions."

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what you're asking for—is it a classical statement that it IS okay to say negative things about the dead as long as one does so in a spirit of generosity? Or would a simple statement that it's okay to say negative things about the dead suffice? In either case, welcome to the site!

Comment: You are giving the translation for bonum and not for bene.